# How to insert data using zip() function

Tags: django

I am trying to insert data after fetching it with `zip()` function but getting an error message. x is the question id, y is the selected answer and `corrected_answer` in `print(x, y, correct_answers)`. I want to save the correct questions by making the value of `is_correct=True` and incorrect answer to `is_correct=False`

[image]

```
@login_required
@student_required
def take_exam(request, pk):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk)
    student = request.user.student
    question = course.questions.filter()  
    #correct_answers = student.course_answers.filter(answer__question__quiz=course, answer__is_correct=True).count()
    total_questions = course.questions.count()
    choice = Answer.objects.filter()
    marks_obtainable = Details.objects.get(course_id=course)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        question_pk = request.POST.getlist('question_pk')
        #question_obj = Question.objects.filter(id=int(question_pk))
        #question_obj = Question.objects.filter(id=question_pk)

        #choice_pk = [request.POST['choice_pk{}'.format(q)] for q in question_obj]
        choice_pk = [request.POST['choice_pk{}'.format(q)] for q in question_pk]

        #print(marks_obtainable.marks_obtained)
        zipped = zip(question_pk, choice_pk)

        for x, y in zipped:
            correct_answers = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=x,  is_correct=True).values("id").first()['id']

            print(x, y, correct_answers)
            if int(y) == int(correct_answers):
                z = TakenQuiz(student=student, course=course, question=x, selected_choice=y,  marks_obtained=marks_obtainable, is_correct=True)
                print("correct")
            else:
                z = TakenQuiz(student=student, course=course, question=x, selected_choice=y,  marks_obtained=marks_obtainable, is_correct=False)
                print("Not Correct")

    return render(request, 'classroom/students/take_exam_form.html', {
        'course': course,
        'question': question,
        'course': course,
        'total_questions': total_questions,
        'choice': choice,
        'marks_obtainable': marks_obtainable 
    })

<form method="post" novalidate>

        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for questions in question %}

        <input type="hidden" name="question_pk" value="{{ questions.pk }}">

        <h3 class="text-info">{{ questions.text|safe }}</h3>


    {% for choices in questions.answers.all %}

        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="choice_pk{{ questions.pk }}" id="choices-{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choices.pk }}">

        <label class="form-check-label" for="choices-{{ forloop.counter }}">
              {{ choices.text|safe }}
        </label>

      {% endfor %}

      {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Now →</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Did you try `question_id=x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on error x should be Question instance.

You need to get Question object for each pk and then zip it.

```
question_pk = [Question.objects.get(pk=pk) for pk in request.POST.getlist('question_pk')]
```

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError at /students/exam/1/ 'choice_pkWhat is your name?'